# Need to do Multiple transaction with SQLServer database

Tags: c#

I have a situation where I need to retrieve records from a table and use those values and pass as parameters for a stored procedure. the stored procedure will reruns a row, and again I need to use the values returned by stored procedure and update other table. Please give me a sample C# code to achieve this scenario. any help would be appropriated.

Thanks in Advance,

Pradeep

Comment: Well just another "Giv'me ze codez"-Questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```
createPROCEDURE MultipleTransaction

    AS
    BEGIN
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
       declare @a int;
      set @a=1;
        -- Insert statements for procedure here
        while((select distinct   id from a  where id =@a) is not null )
        begin
         declare @name varchar(100)
         declare @id int

         set @name =(select distinct   name2 from a  where id =@a)
         set @id =(select distinct   id from a  where id =@a)

         exec   GetRows  @name,@id -- calling another procedure
       set @a =@a+1;
        end
    END


create PROCEDURE  GetRows  
     (@Para varchar(100),@id varchar(10)  )
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
     UPDATE [Cube].[dbo].[b]
   SET [name1] = @Para
 WHERE  id =@id
END
```

Comment: I know this can be achieved by creating new stored proc but unfortunately I am not privileged to create any stored procedure, I need to achieve this by only c# code.

Comment: Well doing this in C# code is really bad because you are producing network roundtrips that are not necessary. May be you talk to the guy with the privilege to do the right thing...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is not possible with my scenario since i am working on a plugin that uses product data. I cannot create tables or procedures.

Comment: Instead of the proc. -> you might dynamically generate a sql statement and execute this on the sql server. With a normal SqlCommand object this should be possible... The SQL code can be the same as for the procedure-body by the way.